# Disable Polymer Drawer Panel Swipe

Tags: jquery, html, properties, polymer, drawer

I tried the three following ways (in the html tag, with .attr() and with .prop() ) but because of the html which is not case-sensitive the attributes "disableSwipe" and "disableEdgeSwipe" are lowercase in the code and Polymer does not detect them. Does anyone have a solution?

```
<paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel" force-narrow disableSwipe disableEdgeSwipe ></paper-drawer-panel>

$("#paperDrawerPanel").attr('disableSwipe', true);
$("#paperDrawerPanel").attr('disableEdgeSwipe', true);

$("#paperDrawerPanel").prop('disableSwipe', true);
$("#paperDrawerPanel").prop('disableEdgeSwipe', true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this won´t work because Attributes in HTML are case insensitive. So when the Polymer documentation says disableEdgeSwipe you have to write disable-edge-swipe.

```
<paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel" force-narrow disable-swipe disable-edge-swipe ></paper-drawer-panel>
```